# Postgres replication via different interfaces

Tags: postgresql, replication

I have one PG master server that replicates itself to one slave server.
Also I would like to replicate this master to slave that is in another network. Master has 2 interfaces, and there are configured 2 networks. If i just add second interface to postgresql.conf, will replication work via both interfaces and networks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can replicate Postgres via different interfaces.
You just need to add all of those slave's IPs to pg_hba.conf to allow connections.
Also you need to add to postgresql.conf IPs of interfaces where to listen to.

```
listen_addresses = 'localhost, ip1_of_this_host, ipN_of_this_host'
```